# how to get date Object when select from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript

I have a drop down list(screenshot attached),when we select any one like this year so how can we send StartIndex and EndIndex in backend using date Object using javascript,angular js.
Thanks In Advance any help will be appriciated

```
StatIndex:2016-01-01T00:00:00+5:30
EndIndex :2016-12-31T23:59:59+5:30

code for Index Range 
 this.indexRanges = ['This Year', 'Last Year', 'This Quarter', 'Last Quarter', 'This Month', 'Last Month', 'This Week',
                    'Last Week', 'Last 72 Hours', 'Last 48 Hours', 'Last 24 Hours', 'Today', 'Yesterday', 'Last Hours', 'This Hours',
                    'This 30 Minutes', 'Last 30 Minutes', 'This 15 Minutes', 'Last 15 Minutes', 'This 10 Minutes', 'Last 10 Minutes'];
```

[image]

Comment: what if i select  'Last Week' as input what is the output you want?

Comment: HI Hassan Thanks For reply value I want is   startIndex:2016-03-07T00:00:00+05:30 EndIndex:2016-03-14T23:59:59+05:30

Comment: You ll have to implement this by your code (means by implementing something that is not  builtin functionality of javascript or angular js) there is no direct way you can do this

Comment: Thanks HassanTariq

Comment: Hi hassan tariq ,is there any way to set timezone in utc using javascript without using any library

Comment: new Date().toUTCString() is the function

Comment: This will convert it into String,I want Date object

Comment: var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(96, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: new Date(Date.UTC(96, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0)); that's mean 1 november 1996 ????

Answer (score 0):

> send in backend using date Object using javascript,angular js

You most likey want the start date:

```
StatIndex:2016-01-01T00:00:00+5:30
```

This can be converted to a `Date` object quite easily using the `Date` constructor. For example:

```
var StatIndex = '2016-01-01T00:00:00+5:30';
const date = Date(StatIndex);
const toSend = {date:date};
const json = JSON.stringify(toSend);
```

Comment: we can't use static values for year 2017 it willn't work

Answer (score 0):

As @Hassan Tariq mentioned in the comments, you need to write your own methods for it. To help you with there is a good library to play with dates [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)